# Bootstrap Theme: Theme hook suggestion for user profiles

Tags: theming, hooks

I've tried to create theme hook suggestions in my template.php to use template files in combination with view modes. My code snippet:

```
function blogtheme_preprocess_user_profile(&$vars) {
 if ($vars['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'blog_user_preview') {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user__blog_user_preview';
 }
 if ($vars['elements']['#view_mode'] == 'blog_user_full') {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'user__blog_user_full';
 }
}
```

But it doesn't work – he standard user-profile.tpl.php is always being used for these two view modes. I activated the zen theme to test the function and it worked smoothly. After reading the comments in the bootstrap base theme I've found the following comment in the registry.inc:

> // Due to how theme() functions, if a base hook implements
>    // preprocess or process functions, then the base hook info is
>    // used to invoke the necessary phase functions instead of the
>    // suggestion hook info. To get around this, a helper function
>    // must be appended to the base hook info so it can call the
>    // theme suggestion implementation's phase function.

```
$function = '_bootstrap_' . $phase . '_theme_suggestion';
 if (!in_array($function, $registry[$base_hook][$phase_key])) {
 $registry[$base_hook][$phase_key][] = $function;
}
```

Could somebody help me by explaining this function? How can I get it to work?

Comment: Why are you using view modes AND templates? The view modes will create the templates, and using something like Display Suite will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: I'm using Display Suite to create view modes and then I'm using theme hook suggestions to combine the template and the created view mode.

Comment: I think what I'm trying to get at is: what are you doing in the template that you can't do in DS?

Comment: Setting the theme hook suggestion to pinpoint a view mode to a specific template.

Comment: No, I mean on a much higher level. WHAT in the template is so important or specialized that you NEED to use a template instead of just using the view mode?

Comment: I have an author block below my nodes which I've written directly into the template file. I want the user profiles to look similar without styling it again.

Comment: What Drupal version? Please tag your question with a Drupal version.

Comment: I was using Drupal 7.x

Answer (score 0):

The code in your first snippet looks correct to me. I would try the following:

1. Remove the `if` statements temporarily and get rid of the second option. It's possible that neither of them are returning true.
2. Theme functions are cached. Make sure you have cleared the cache before testing.
3. Double check that your custom template is named `user--blog_user_preview.tpl.php`.

Comment: Removing the if statements worked. Debugged even $vars with dpm and it has been stated, that the current used view mode is user__blog_user_preview but it still didn't work (user-profile.tpl.php is being used).